# blog cover image thats not in the blog post

Tags: wordpress, blogs, blogger

I've been asked to integrate a blog into an existing website.
The blog content will be hosted with an external blog provider (im thinking wordpress and blogger) and I would then import the posts onto the clients site via an ATOM feed as this is the simplest way I can see of doing all this.

The issue I'm facing is that when the blog list is displayed on the clients site they want to use a grid based layout with a cover image. Another stipulation of the design is that the cover image should also not be part of the actual blog post content. 
Ideally it would be great if the blogging provider (wordpress/blogger) supported uploading additional metadata and images that do not go into the blog post's HTML content.

I cant find any way of doing this currently and am wondering if I have any options other than rolling my own mini blogging platform for the client or installing wordpress locally and setting that up.
Any ideas?

Comment: Where exactly do you visualize these metadata to be going, apart from each post? Even better, where in the feed would these cover images be going?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will let you upload a custom header image. See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers - this will be useful if you want the same header image on every page. If you want a different header image 'per post' then you'll need a plugin to do that. There are some good plugins that do that in the WP plugin repo: http://wordpress.org/plugins/